# Unable to call JavaScript prototype function from angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-events

I am trying to call a JavaScript prototype function from ng-click of hyperlink as follows. But I am unable to fire the `getInfo()` function on link click. Am I missing any basics or doing wrong?

This is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function Apple() {
        this.type = "fff";
        this.color = "red";

    }
    Apple.prototype.getInfo = function () {
        alert( this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple');
    };
    var appl = new Apple();
});
```

This is my html:

```
  <a href="" ng-click="appl.getInfo()">click</a>
```

Comment: where is your controller

Comment: you should create the object in controller and assign the appl to the scope

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your above code, I *believe* the problem is that you're not exposing `appl` to your via (via the `$scope`). You need to do something more like this:

```
var MyController = function($scope) {
  function Apple() {
    this.type = "fff";
    this.color = "red";

  };
  Apple.prototype.getInfo = function () {
    alert( this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple');
  };
  $scope.appl = new Apple();
};
```

And then:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
   <a href="" ng-click="appl.getInfo()">click</a>
</div>
```

To elaborate a little more, expressions like the ones passed to Angular's `ngClick` are evaluated within the context of an Angular `$scope` (not within the context of their location in the DOM). You can see this by checking out the [source of `ngClick`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L64)

Comment: How can I do the same thing with out angularjs? Imagine If i click a link i want to call a prototype function. I am little confused why do I have to create a controller and pass it through scope for just click event.

Comment: You don't need angular JS at all for what you're describing. But you *are* using it when you use `ngClick`. You could just as easily use `onclick` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) in which case your code should work as-is.

Comment: I am able to call a javascript function on click of a hyperlink but not the prototype function. this is the problem.

Comment: What you mean by "a function" is too ambiguous. Your question needs more context. A Plunker would be a good start.

Comment: @user3501278 You may be unfamiliar with what scope is. Your `appl` variable is only available within the document.ready function because you declared it there. So the scope of appl within the document.ready function. Novice programmers would put everything on glocal scope `window.appl = ...` but it would be best to not put anylthing on glocal scope (except the root namespace of your application). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29

Comment: i created a plunker. I am unable to call the getInfo function on checkbox click event. I don't want to use scope but just a regular click event.      http://plnkr.co/edit/efCbsSJysNX0XWoCBTC6?p=preview

Comment: When you declare a variable inside of jQuery's `$()` wrapper, it's not visible outside of that function (unless you attach it to the window). This is how JavaScript scoping works. So you need to either 1: use `$scope` or 2: Move it outside of jQuery's `$()` ready handler. I'll post a JSbin...